# configure: error: You need 32-bits luac when using using lua from contrib

Tags: virtualbox, compiling, vlc

I installed ubuntu 13.10 64 bits on virtualbox. I am trying to compile vlc using these steps:

https://wiki.videolan.org/Win32Compile/

When I reached this step:

```
 ../extras/package/win32/configure.sh --host=i586-mingw32msvc
```

(I used `host=i686-w64-mingw32` as explained in the link),
I got this error:

```
configure: error: You need 32-bits luac when using using lua from contrib.
```

I am a newbie at this. Would someone please explain how to fix this?

I have windows 7 64 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that you need the 32-bit libraries of lua scripts:

```
sudo apt-get install liblua5.1-0-dev:i386
```

That should do it. As I see it, you will lack tons of libraries, so you should also use:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep vlc
```

to install all the libraries. Also, if you are building as target Windows 64-bits you should use `x86_64-w64-mingw32` instead `i586-mingw32msvc` as said in the instructions:

> This is known as the host triplet, although it's more of a pair than a
>   triplet in the case of Mingw. The exact value depends on your
>   installation of the toolchain. Notably on Debian/Ubuntu, these values
>   must be used:
>
> ```
> i686-w64-mingw32 for Windows 32-bits, using the Mingw-w64 toolchain
> x86_64-w64-mingw32 for Windows 64-bits, using the Mingw-w64 toolchain
> i586-mingw32msvc for Windows 32-bits, using the Mingw32 toolchain
> ```
>
> Again, you **MUST** substitute the value in the following command
>   snippets.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was confused about the triplet as well. I am trying to build vlc 32 bit version, does this mean I should use "for Windows 32-bits"?

Comment: mm... why are you building for windows 32-bits if you use 64-bits? The best is using 64-bits to 64-bits, that way you save a lot of time figuring out the build dependencies.

Comment: I am developing a c# application that uses the vlc activex plugin and I used the 32 bit version of vlc so it runs on both.

Comment: Exactly the point. 64-bits binaries in windows normally can run 32-bit libraries without problem.

Comment: make finished successfully. Would you please help me to do this: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?p=388113#p388113 , and where should I find the dll after make?

Comment: You should ask to the developer itself.